# Cope with Bacon.js's side effects

Tags: ajax, coffeescript, purely-functional, bacon.js

I'm a newbie to the Bacon.js, usually write programs in Haskell.
By my experience with Haskell, I want to describe some situations in Bacon.js as purely-functional-like approach.

Here is an example situation.

- `triggerStream` is a source stream.
- `resultStream` tries ajax access when `triggerStream`'s events occur.
- `resultStream2` also tries ajax access after completion of `resultStream`'s ajax access.

This is my approach:

```
### =======
# Streams
# ======= ###
triggerStream = () ->
  Bacon.fromArray([1,2,3])

resultStream = 
  triggerStream()
    .flatMap((n) -> Bacon.fromPromise($.ajax(toAjax n)))
    .zip(triggerStream(), (r,t) ->
      {result: r, trigger: t}

resultStream2 =
  resultStream     # (*)
    .flatMap((o) -> Bacon.fromPromise($.ajax(toAjax2 o)))
    .zip(resultStream, (r2,r1) ->
      {result: r2, trigger: r1.trigger}

### =======
# Assignments
# ======= ###

triggerStream()
  .onValue(beforeAjax1) # (a)
resultStream
  .onValue(afterAjax1)  # (b)
resultStream2
  .onValue(afterAjax2)  # (c)
```

(a) is supporsed to be executed after each trigger event, in other words it's executed before `resultStream`'s ajax access.

(b) is supporsed to be fired after `resultStream`'s ajax access.

(c) is supporsed to be start after `resultStream2`'s ajax access.

I know Bacon.js's streams or properties have side effects on themselves, and so my code can't work well.
In (b), `resultStream`'s events are removed from `resultStream` object, which causes the empty stream in (*).

The approach which changes `resultStream` to a function (like `triggerStream`) seams work well, but it causes independent two times `resultStream`'s ajax access when (b) and (c).

Is there any idea to realize my approach?

Comment: The problem is in that you use Bacon.fromArray as the source. Bacon.fromArray returns a stream that has a bit funky behaviour, in the sense that it spits its contents out to the first subscriber. You might try a more realistic source such as Bacon.sequentially to make this work.

Comment: The fact about Bacon.fromArray is new to me. Thanks so much! But it doesn't seem to work yet... 
`onValue()` at (b) eats all stream and (c) doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, but I was misunderstood.
Your's worked. Awesome!

Comment: @raimohanska you should post your comment as an answer, so that this quiestion would be marked as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in that you use `Bacon.fromArray` as the source. This method returns a synchrously responding stream that practicaly spits its contents out to the first subscriber.

You might try a more realistic source such as `Bacon.sequentially` to make this work. Or you may do `stream.delay(0)` to change it into an asynchronously responding one.

See also the Bacon.js FAQ: https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/wiki/FAQ#why-isnt-my-subscriber-called